# Implementing IntelliSense-like behavior in custom editors for domain-specific languages

Tags: types, intellisense, dsl

I'm creating a DSL with a template-like editor, much like the rule systems in [Alice](http://www.allice.org).  Users will be able to select relationships from a list as well as the objects to apply the relation to.  These two lists should be filtered based on the acceptable types -- for instance, if the relationship is "greater than" then the available objects must be of a type that "greater than" is implemented for.

Similarly, if an object is selected that is *not* comparable with greater than, then that relation should not be in the list of potential relations.  I think the heart of this problem is a type checker, but I'm not certain of the best way to incorporate that type of logic in my application.  Is anyone aware of existing type checking libraries for DSLs?

I am specifically interested in open-source and cross-platform technologies.  Java is probably the language we will end up using, but that is not fixed.

Comment: I'm wondering what happened with this? Did you find a good solution? In my mind, Intellisense would be monstrously difficult to implement from a usability point of view. Finding the right balance between responsiveness and intrusiveness seems like an incredibly fiddly task. From my experience, Microsoft's implementation is miles ahead of anything else. The Eclipse implementation feels so clunky. I'd be very interested to know if you found something good.

Comment: This was a work project, and I was pulled off to work on another project, so my efforts on this (sortof) died off.  Other than that, I think you (Alex) and I are interested in different aspects of 'intellisense'.  Rather than working on the actual user interface, I was more concerned with the design behind a general-purpose auto-complete system.  (The UI would come later.)

Answer (score 2):

You might look into [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/). It's the editing component used by Notepad++, among other tools. It has some support for doing autocompletion, although I haven't tried using it myself, so I'm not sure how well it works. It's open source, so if it doesn't meet your needs, you can extend it without too much hassle, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This might help on the intellisense side - [CodeTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/codetextbox.aspx)